# Convert Trezor seed to Monero compatible seed on Windows?

Tags: mnemonic-seed, windows, trezor

My Trezor HW is stolen and I can’t access my funds. I have my Trezor seed but I can’t enter it in Monero wallets, as it has the wrong length. How do I convert the seed?

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** Entering your seed on your computer can potentially expose it to malware if your computer is compromised.

---

First step is to download `Git for Windows`.

- Go to [gitforwindows.org](https://gitforwindows.org) and use the Download button.
- Install it with default settings.

Next step is to install Python 3.

- Go to [python.org](https://python.org) and download the latest `Python 3 Windows x86-64 executable installer`. I used the following link: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.7/python-3.10.7-amd64.exe
- Open the installer, select `Add Python 3.10 to PATH` and then install with default settings.

Afterwards open the `git-bash` shell the following way.

- Open the following path: `C:\Program Files\Git` in Explorer.
- Start `git-bash.exe` as administrator, maximize the window.

Then enter the following commands, line by line.

- `git clone --recursive https://github.com/ph4r05/monero-agent`
- `cd monero-agent`
- `pip3 install .[poc,trezor]`

The tool has now been installed. Use the following command to convert your Trezor seed to a Monero compatible seed. Make sure to replace the words starting with `permit ...` with your Trezor seed.

```
monero-seed --slip0010 -- 'permit universe parent weapon amused modify essay borrow tobacco budget walnut lunch consider gallery ride amazing frog forget treat market chapter velvet useless topple'
```

The program will now print your Monero compatible seed under the line starting with `Seed Monero wrds`.